# Toggle color on click

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a list with `<a href>` and I'm trying to set the color on click.

```
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="621">Test 1</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="622">Test 2</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="639">Test 3</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="641">Test 4</a>
```

I've achieved that with the following code:

```
const homeCategoryList = document.querySelectorAll('#mls-category-terms');
for (let i = 0; i < homeCategoryList.length; i++) {
    homeCategoryList[i].addEventListener('click', () => homeCategoryList[i].setAttribute('style', 'background: #3d5b9a;color: #fff;'));
}
```

This works, but in this way when I click on another link the color shows up on that link too, but it stays on the previous link as well.

So, the perfect result will be when the user clicks on one link it gets a different color, but if click on another link from that list the previous one will be reset and the last clicked one will get the color.

Here is the image of the current result: https://prnt.sc/12sr23w

Hope that makes sense. I'm quite a newbie in JavaScript.

Comment: First of all, IDs should be unique. Secondly, why don't you use CSS?

Comment: Yea, use unique IDs or not if there is no need. And use CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the previous one that got a style and remove it accordingly:

```js
const homeCategoryList = document.querySelectorAll('#mls-category-terms');
let PREV=0;
for (let i = 0; i < homeCategoryList.length; i++) {
    homeCategoryList[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      homeCategoryList[PREV].removeAttribute('style');
      homeCategoryList[i].setAttribute('style', 'background: #3d5b9a;color: #fff;')
      PREV=i;
    });
}
```

```html
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="621">Test 1</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="622">Test 2</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="639">Test 3</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="641">Test 4</a>
```

Comment: You could use a `let` instead of a global.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment, IDs should be unique therefore `mls-category-terms` should be a CSS class. Once you fixed that, you can do:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.mls-category-terms');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    links.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active')); // remove the 'active' class from all links
    link.classList.add('active'); // add the 'active' class only to the clicked one
  })
});
```

```css
.mls-category-terms.active {
  background-color: #3d5b9a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a id="link1" class="mls-category-terms 621">Test 1</a>
<a id="link2" class="mls-category-terms 622">Test 2</a>
<a id="link3" class="mls-category-terms 639">Test 3</a>
<a id="link4" class="mls-category-terms 641">Test 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each click removes the styles that were previously set before adding styles to the newly clicked element.

```js
const homeCategoryList = document.querySelectorAll('#mls-category-terms');
homeCategoryList.forEach(h => h.addEventListener('click', () => toggleColor(h)));

function toggleColor(e) {
  homeCategoryList.forEach(f => f.setAttribute('style', 'background:;color:;'));
  e.setAttribute('style', 'background: #3d5b9a;color: #fff;');
}
```

```html
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="621">Test 1</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="622">Test 2</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="639">Test 3</a>
<a id="mls-category-terms" class="641">Test 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done with the CSS `:focus` pseudo-class:

```css
.mls-category-terms:link {color:#000}
.mls-category-terms:visited {color:#000}
.mls-category-terms:hover {color:#FF00FF}
.mls-category-terms:active {color:#0000FF}
.mls-category-terms:focus {
  background: #3d5b9a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="mls-category-terms 621" href="#">Test 1</a>
<a class="mls-category-terms 622" href="#">Test 2</a>
<a class="mls-category-terms 639" href="#">Test 3</a>
<a class="mls-category-terms 641" href="#">Test 4</a>
```

This *was* my preferred method, but as [secan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484234/toggle-color-on-click/67484615?noredirect=1#comment119284424_67484615) below shows, because the `:focus` pseudo class loses focus regardless of what other element is clicked. Hence, using an `.active` class and Javascript would be best for the majority of use-cases.

Note also that the `mls-category-terms` id has been turned into a class.

Comment: The problem with using the `:focus` pseudo-class is that as soon as the user clicks on any other element in the page, the link will lose focus and roll back to the default style. If the "active" style should be preserved from the moment a link is clicked until another link is clicked, I think you have to use JavaScript.